# Open Waze GPS navigation or google map with Intent

Tags: java, android, dictionary, android-intent, gps

I try to open the navigation with a click of a button, in the choice of gps applications, I waze and google maps. When I click on google map, the navigation starts correctly but when I click on waze navigation does not start. I just get my position

```
Intent intent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW,

Uri.parse("google.navigation:q=22+dizengoff+street+netanya"));
            startActivity(intent);
```

Ir all my code:

```
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    getWindow().setSoftInputMode(
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_HIDDEN); //Que le clavier soit par defaut ferme

    init();
}

public void init(){
    //Reglage des bouton par ID
    btnAdd = findViewById(R.id.maAddUser);
    btnMap = findViewById(R.id.maBtnMap);


    //On click sur les boutons
    btnAdd.setOnClickListener(this);
    btnMap.setOnClickListener(this);
}


@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()){
        case R.id.maAddUser:
            //Redirection vers l'activity ADDUSER
            Intent goAddUser = new Intent(MainActivity.this, AddUserActivity.class);
            startActivity(goAddUser); //Redirection vers ADD USER
            break;
        case R.id.maBtnMap:
            Intent intent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW,
                    Uri.parse("google.navigation:q=22+dizengoff+street+netanya"));
            startActivity(intent);
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you please provide more of your code?

Comment: look at my code

Answer (score 1):

It's an old question but there is a new library https://github.com/pkitools/Android-Location-Navigator

That can do Waze and Google or multiple choice navigations

Answer (score 0):

Also struggling with this. 
Seems you can use:

```
String uri = "google.navigation:q=" + position.latitude + "," + position.longitude;
```

to start navigation in google maps, or

```
String uri = "geo:0,0?q=" + position.latitude + "," + position.longitude;
```

to start navigation in waze. I can't find a sollution that works seamlessly in both BUT the latter does display a pin in the location on a google map so only requires one extra button tap for directions(still unacceptable ux for me).

Answer (score 0):

```
try {
    // Launch Waze
    String mapRequest = "https://waze.com/ul?q=" + latLng.latitude + "," + latLng.longitude + "&navigate=yes&zoom=17";
    Uri gmmIntentUri = Uri.parse(mapRequest);
    Intent mapIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, gmmIntentUri);
    mapIntent.setPackage("com.waze");
    startActivity(mapIntent);

    } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
    // If Waze is not installed, open it in Google Play
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("market://details?id=com.waze"));
    startActivity(intent);
    }
```

Comment: please refer:  https://developers.google.com/waze/deeplinks/#navigate-to-location